# Ruby: How do I use regex to return all matches?

Tags: ruby

I can intersect two arrays by doing:

```
keyphrase_matches = words & city.keywords
```

How can I achieve the same thing using regular expression? I want to test one array against a regular expression and get a new array with the matches.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `words & city.keywords`, except that the result is an array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Enumerable#grep`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) method:

```
%w{a b c 1 2 3}.grep /\d/ # => ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `array.grep(regex)` to return all elements that match the given regex.

See [`Enumerable#grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep).

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, if `arr1` and `arr2` are two arrays of strings (though you did not say they contain strings), you want to know if a regular expression could be used to produce `arr1 & arr2`.

First some test data:

```
arr1 = "Now is the time for all good Rubyists".split
  #=> ["Now", "is", "the", "time", "for", "all", "good", "Rubyists"]
arr2 = "to find time to have the good life".split
  #=> ["to", "find", "time", "to", "have", "the", "good", "life"]
```

The result we want:

```
arr1 & arr2
  #=> ["the", "time", "good"]
```

I can think of two ways you might use use `Enumerable#grep`, as suggested by @meagar and @August:

**#1**

```
arr1.select { |e| arr2.grep(/#{e}/).any? }
  #=> ["the", "time", "good"]
```

**#2**

```
regex = Regexp.new("#{arr2.join('|')}") 
  #=> /to|find|time|to|have|the|good|life/
arr1.grep(regex)
  #=> ["the", "time", "good"]
```

Of course, `Array#&` generally would be preferred, especially in [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).